# Why doesn't C# LinkedList.RemoveFirst() return the removed value?

Tags: c#, collections, api-design

Is there some idiomatic, performance or design philosophy reason why C#'s LinkedList's RemoveFirst() and RemoveLast() operations don't return the value removed?

Right now, if I want to read and remove the first value, I believe the incantation is:

```
LinkedList<string> list = ...;
...
string removed = list.First.Value;
list.RemoveFirst();
```

In Java, it would be:

```
LinkedList<String> list = ...;
...
String removed = list.removeFirst();
```

Don't get me wrong; I am not trying to say Java is better. C#'s LinkedList has many more affordances, simply by exposing the Node as a public construct. I am trying to understand the design choices.

Comment: To me, it seems like it comes down to precision in method naming.  The method should do exactly what it says.  What if it were easy to remove the first item but difficult to read its value?  (We know that's not the case here, but it could be so in a `RemoveFirst` method in a different case, like a hypothetical `Directory.RemoveFirst`).

Comment: well i think you can Override these methods and build you're own.

Comment: I have not checked, but I doubt very much that you can override these methods. In C#, unlike Java, methods are not virtual by default -- you have to declare them with the `virtual` keyword if you want to allow them to be overridden. Also, even still, when overriding a method, you can't change its return type.

Comment: Because its return type is void ☺

Comment: Although you CAN declare the method any way you want to if you use the `new` keyword. However, the `new` keyword does not automatically make a non-virtual method into a virtual one; instead it replaces the method. Any parent classes of the class you are overriding will not correctly call the new version of your "overriden" method. They will call the method in the parent class.

Comment: You could also declare an extension method, something like "RemoveAndReturnFirst" that takes a LinkedList and performs the operation you want. You can't keep the name because overloads can't be selected based on return type.

Comment: @Justin, the designers still had the opportunity to return the node itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't really give a definitive answer, as I can't read the minds of the designers of `LinkedList<T>`. What I *can* say is this.

In Java, the `LinkedList<E>` class implements the `Queue<E>` interface, which reflects a decision on the designers' part: "You know what? A linked list can easily be used as a queue, so we might as well have it implement that interface." And the way you interact with a *queue* is by popping items off the end, and then, you know, *using* them for something (which means it's natural for a `Pop`-like operation to return the element popped).

In .NET, there is no `IQueue<T>` interface. Basically, the designers made a different decision: "The most efficient implementation of queue-like behavior we know of is a simple array-based circular queue. So if developers want a queue, they should use the `Queue<T>` class, which is exactly that."

If a developer wants to use a `LinkedList<T>` as a *queue* (or a *deque* for that matter), chances are he/she is picking the wrong implementation for the data structure he/she actually needs (from the .NET point of view).

Thus, in the spirit of "a proper function should do exactly one thing," the BCL folks opted to make `LinkedList<T>.RemoveFirst` do just that: remove the first element (similar to how `List<T>.RemoveAt` just removes the element at the specified index and returns nothing).

I'm not saying either decision is right or wrong. I think the different interfaces of the standard linked list class in Java and .NET simply reflect different views of what a linked list *is* and how it should be *used* within the two frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

The programmer may not always want to return the first node when removing it. If `RemoveFirst` returned the node and the programmer did not need it, it would still require memory allocation and disposal. Optionally storing the first node (using the `First` property) and having a separate remove function seems more flexible, in my opinion.

Comment: I had not considered the value type argument. In Java, the returned value would be an object reference; somewhere between 4 and 8 bytes. But since C# allows much larger value types, I can see how that may incur some non-negligible penalty.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a Queue or a Stack collection instead of a LinkedList?  you can then push and pop and get the behavior you desire.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I am using. But I was still curious about this API design choice. Seems like returning a void is a 'waste' of an opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `RemoveFirst` and `RemoveLast` doesn't actually return the value is that internally the `LinkedList<T>` stores nodes as `LinkedListNode<T>`. The `LinkedListNode` object has a concept of `Next` and `Previous` but if you remove the object from the parent collection where would these properties point?

Comment: Just because the value is wrapped in a node doesn't mean the API cannot return the value. Furthermore, returning the node itself is an alternative to returning null.

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga, I agree that it could and probably should return the node's `Value` property. I think the reason that they (Microsoft) didn't do it that way was because it would be inconsistent with the rest of the methods such as `Find` and `Add` which all return nodes.

Comment: But returning the node would have been OK too... The more I think about it, the more I think the decision was driven by some design philosophy.

Comment: I totally agree that it was a design philosophy. However, if it returned a node would you expect `Next` and `Previous` to be null then? This is where I think it broke down when designing it. A removed node pretty much only has a `Value` property, everything else is worthless. So MS decided it wouldn't make sense to return a worthless object. But, they also didn't want to change the pattern of methods turning nodes so they couldn't just return the raw value. So instead they took the road that works for nobody and returned nothing. That's just my guess. I would have returned the `Value`.